# expressjs 4 serving CSS file with HTML in it instead of the expected CSS

Tags: node.js, express, sass, gruntjs, pug

Express 4 is serving a `style.css` file but not the one that grunt-sass is compiling which is `public/stylesheets/style.css`. What is stranger is that the `style.css` file that is being served contains the compressed HTML code that is being generated from the `app/views/index.jade` file. Any ideas what is happening here?

### My Project Info & Files

---

my `app/views/index.jade`

```
doctype html

html
  head
    link(href="/favicon.ico", rel="shortcut icon", type="image/x-icon")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/public/stylesheets/style.css")
  body
    h1 Hello World
    script(src='http://localhost:35729/livereload.js')
```

---

my `scss/style.scss`

```
h1 { color : red; }
```

---

my `public/stylesheets/style.css` that is generated upon running `grunt`. so this is proof that my `scss/style,scss` is being compiled properly

```
h1{color:red;}
```

---

my `server.js`

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path');

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/app/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// make sure to coordinate client side and server side routes
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

var port = 3030;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port + '...');
```

---

my `Gruntfile.js`

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'), 

    sass: {
      options: {
        includePaths: ['public/vendor/foundation/scss']
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          outputStyle: 'compressed'
        },
        files: {
          'public/stylesheets/style.css' : 'scss/style.scss'
        }
      }
    },

    watch: {
      source: {
        files: ['scss/**/*.scss', 'Gruntfile.js'],
        tasks: ['sass'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass','watch']);
}
```

---

my `package.json`

{
  "name": "my-project",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jade": "*",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "monk": "*",
    "less": "^1.7.0",
    "express": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.4",
    "grunt-sass": "^0.12.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "node-sass": "^0.8.6"
  }
}

---

my project tree

```
.
├── app
│   └── views
│       └── index.jade
├── bower.json
├── class3s.js
├── Gruntfile.js
├── node_modules
│   ├── express
│   ├── grunt
│   ├── grunt-contrib-watch
│   ├── grunt-sass
│   ├── jade
│   ├── mongodb
│   ├── monk
│   ├── node-sass
│   └── npm-debug.log
├── old-server.js
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   ├── stylesheets
│   └── vendor
├── README.md
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── user.js
├── scss
│   ├── _settings.scss
│   └── style.scss
└── server.js
```

---

the `style.css` that chromium shows me in Developer Tools

[image]

Here it is in full:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body><h1>Hello World</h1><script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

`link(rel="stylesheet", href="/public/stylesheets/style.css")`

to:

`link(rel="stylesheet", href="/stylesheets/style.css")`

When you do `express.static(__dirname + '/public')`, you're setting `__dirname + '/public'` as the location of the root web path (`/`). So a request for `/stylesheets/style.css` will be looked up on the file system as `__dirname + '/public/stylesheets/style.css'`.

Without the above change, the static middleware looks up `__dirname + '/public/public/stylesheets/style.css'` and fails, so it continues on to the next middleware or route, which is how your index.jade is getting rendered for the css.

Comment: thanks that fixed it. do you have any idea why the style.css file served contained the HTML generated by index.jade?

Comment: As noted in the answer: Without the above change, the static middleware looks up `__dirname + '/public/public/stylesheets/style.css'` and fails, so it continues on to the next middleware or route, which is how your index.jade is getting rendered for the css.

Comment: yes I see. sometimes i get too emotional and rush through answers. i will try to be more mindful of this. thanks again.